# Having trouble to pass data to a modal in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, modal-dialog

I have the following code

```js
$scope.currentTask = undefined;

$scope.openModal = function (task, size, parentSelector) {  
        var parentElem = parentSelector ? 
                      angular.element($document[0].querySelector('.modal-demo ' + parentSelector)) : undefined;
        
        var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
            animation: true,
            ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-title',
            ariaDescribedBy: 'modal-body',
            templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
            controller: 'homeController',
            controllerAs: '$ctrl',
            scope: $scope,
            size: size,
            appendTo: parentElem,
            resolve: {
                items: function () {
                  return $scope.items;
                }
            }
        });

        $rootScope.currentModal = modalInstance;

        $rootScope.currentModal.result.then(function () {
        }, function () {
            $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
        });
}

$scope.setTask = function(task) {
  $scope.currentTask = task;
}

$scope.log = function (currentTask) {
   console.log($scope.currentTask);
}
```

```html
<div class="row" ng-init="processPages()">
 <div class="panel panel-default col-xs-3" style="margin: 20px" ng-repeat = "list in pages[currentPage]">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
   <div class="panel-heading">
    <h6 style = "float: right">({{list.tasks.length}})</h6>
    <div class="panel-title">
     <h4>{{list.name}}</h4>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
   <table class="table table-striped table-hover" ng-init = "tasks = list.tasks">
    <tr ng-repeat="task in tasks">
     <td ng-click="setTask(task); openModal(task);>  
       <h5>{{task.name}}</h5>
     </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </div>
 </div> 
</div>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
 <div ng-init="editEnabled = false">
        <div class="modal-header" ng-init = "log(currentTask)">
            <h3 class="modal-title" id="modal-title" ng-show = "!editEnabled">Not editing</h3>
            <h3 class="modal-title" id="modal-title" ng-show = "editEnabled">Editing</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" id="modal-body">
         <div ng-show="!editEnabled">

         </div>
         <div ng-show="editEnabled">
    
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
         <button style = "float: left" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-show = "!editEnabled" ng-click="editEnabled = true">Editar</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
            <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
        </div>
 </div>
</script>
```

Here's how the page is working:

[First we have a list of tasks and if we click on one task...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G95iR.png)

[...we get a model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4Xfd.png)

I'd like the task information to be passed to the model, but everytime I set the task on the $scope to be the task on the list, even though it happens before the model is opened the log function prints the currentTask is still undefined. I've tried to change the currentTask definition at the beggining to be something concrete, but what happens then is the log function prints what was defined at the beggining and not after the change is made.

Comment: Your problem is, your assigning your controller to the modal. Therefore the modal has its own instance of homecontroller created due to this, information that you try and pass in gets overridden by the modals own stuff. Remove the controller and if you need a controller still, make one explicitly for the modal. At least I think thats what the problem is. If thats not the case, ill recreate your code in a project and do some more testing. Let me know :)

Comment: Hey man, thanks for the answer. I tried removing the controller declaration of the controller but stil didn't work :( I then tried removing the scope declaration inside model too, but then I couldn't get anything from my scope inside it any longer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution I could find that worked was creating a different controller for the modal and sharing data between modalController and homeController via service. It's working fine, here's the service:

```
var app = angular.module('agendaApp');

app.service('sharedModalProperties', function() {
    var task = undefined;
    var activeModal = undefined;

    return {
        setCurrentTask : function (task) {
           this.task = task;
        },

        getCurrentTask : function () {
            return this.task;
        },

        setActiveModal : function (modal) {
            this.modal = modal;
        },

        getActiveModal : function () {
            return this.modal;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

From our discussion in the comments try something like this for your uibmodal's controller (See the [git repo](https://github.com/saviofelixmuniz/AgendaCompleta/tree/ModalFixes) for the changes I made)

```
...
$scope.items = ["items1", "items2", "items3"];
var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
  animation: true,
  ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-title',
  ariaDescribedBy: 'modal-body',
  templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
  size: size,
  appendTo: parentElem,
  resolve: {
    modalItems: function() {
      console.log("items to send to modal", $scope.items);
      return $scope.items;
    }
  },
  controller: ['$scope', 'modalItems', function($scope, modalItems) {
    console.log("items sent to modal", modalItems);
    $scope.modalItems = modalItems;
  }]
});
...
```

HTML:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
{{modalItems}}  <!-- Should show the array of items -->
</script>
```

Comment: Still not updating:'( Appreciate the effort,though.
Changed to:
 modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
            animation: true,
            ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-title',
            ariaDescribedBy: 'modal-body',
            templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
            scope: $scope,
            size: size,
            appendTo: parentElem,
            controller: function($scope, task) {
                $scope.currentTask = task;
            },
            resolve: {
                task: function () {
                  return $scope.currentTask;
            }
        }

Comment: I have $scope.currentTask = {name : "taskIncorrect"} in my scope, and the setTask sets it to $scope.currentTask = {name: "taskCorrect"}. But when asking doing log(currentTask) I still get the taskIncorrect one

Comment: Remove the $scope attribute. Since you're passing in the task information thats required. :) Once again it seems to be overwriting. Might be wrong though..

Comment: When I remove it nothing is passed and I can't even get in the $scope.log function :(

Comment: I could send you my github repository if you have some more time

Comment: @SávioMuniz Sure man. Send away. My github account is the same as my username here.

Comment: I added you as a collaborator, sorry I took long, it was already 2 am here in Brazil and I was really tired

Comment: @SávioMuniz No worries. Im going to work in a branch and try and make it work. Ill submit my tweaks here once it's working.

Comment: @SávioMuniz Made a pull request: https://github.com/saviofelixmuniz/AgendaCompleta/pull/3

Answer (score 0):

The task being undefined indicates the modal popup's ($scope) is not aware of any such model data. I assume its creating a fresh scope object, so your call to setTask() does not work as it is working on old scope. You can try calling during your modal display code.

```
$scope.openModal = function (task, size, parentSelector) {  
        var parentElem = parentSelector ? 
                      angular.element($document[0].querySelector('.modal-demo ' + parentSelector)) : undefined;

        var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
            animation: true,
            ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-title',
            ariaDescribedBy: 'modal-body',
            templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
            controller: 'homeController',
            controllerAs: '$ctrl',
            scope: $scope,
            size: size,
            appendTo: parentElem,
            resolve: {
                items: function () {
                  return $scope.items;
                }
            }
        });


        $rootScope.currentModal = modalInstance;

        $rootScope.currentModal.result.then(function () {
        }, function () {
            $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
        }

        //Add this code
        $scope.currentTask = task;
          //Or Call Set Task Here.
          setTask(task);

        );
}
```